# step by step simulation in command line for Matlab Simulink model

Tags: command-line, simulink

I want a solution for command line implementation for Matlab Simulink. In simulink model there is simulation switch called "step forward". With this I am able to run step by step and able to see the outputs in scope for each sample time.

I am also able to change some inputs for constant input blocks at any sample period time. However, I want to do this in command line, because I have a huge model and I want to reuse this model verification script.

I am able to do some thing like this using "sim" command. But the sim command is just simulating the entire model at once, and I could not observe/change the intermediate outputs/inputs. The "sim" command with a certain stop time is running for certain sample periods, but later if I give the next "sim" command, it is running from the beginning and not starting from where it stopped. But, is there any exact Matlab command to step and pause (for one sample period time) the simulation, like that in simulink gui.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `SimState` to save the states of the model at the end of one simulation, and restore them at the beginning of the next simulation. How to do this is described in the documentation under [Save and Restore Simulation State as SimState](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/saving-and-restoring-the-simulation-state-as-the-simstate.html).

You cannot make any structural changes to the model (e.g. add or remove block) between each call to `sim`. There are also a few blocks which don't support `SimState`, see the documentation for more details. Note that this is for the latest release (R2015a), more and more blocks were added to support `SimState` over the past few years, so you want to check the [release notes](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/release-notes.html) depending on the release you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
sldebug('gcs');
```

you are now in debug mode, you can type in help to get an overview of the available commands. To run through the model type in:

```
next
```

Each time you type next, you move the simulation one step forwards.

The following link will provide you with further details on how stepping through a simulation works.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/how-stepping-through-a-simulation-works.html

For more details on using the debugger to run through the simulation step by step you can go to:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/running-a-simulation-step-by-step.html